# Windows limitation to the length of command line parameters

Tags: windows

`program.exe file1 file2 ... file10000` won't work.

Windows have weird limitation to the length of command line parameters. It something between 32683 and 32853 characters. Is there any other way to pass parameters?

Comment: Going to guess the max character limit is 32,767 (max value of a signed 16-bit integer).  No idea if there's another way of passing parameters but if you wrote the program, wouldn't it be better to pass the directory name as a parameter instead?

Comment: @johnh, yes this is proper way of doing it. However, my `program.exe` doesn't allow dirs. Also, I cannot pass parameters by parts (1-1000 first, 1001-2000 second etc). And more importantly I don't own source code to modify it.

Comment: What does this program do?  Maybe there are alternatives that will work.

Comment: @ShyMan Yeah we could use some more information here.  I really want to suggest using a batch file for this but your comment about being unable to pass the parameters in groups means that's not probably an option.  So I guess the question I have is, why can't you pass the parameters in groups?  Is it really not possible to collect the output of each group, then grouping that output to create the desired result?

Comment: Also, how many more files are you wanting to use?

Comment: @johnh, No, I cannot divide this job, it must be atomic. It's related with data compression. So if you take different data sets they will have different statistical properties. ~100k files

Comment: @ShyMan Ah ok that makes sense.  The ~100k files means you can't even rename them or use short filenames.  I'm not really sure what else you can do.

Comment: @MBraedley, I cannot replace this tool for any other.

Comment: @ShyMan Although [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) isn't current in terms of Windows 7, I believe this describes your potential choices.  However, they all center on modification of the program itself.

Comment: I'm guessing the program can't pull the parameters from a text file or something?

Comment: this answer [Maximum Length of Command Line String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452546/995714) explains why the limit is 32767 characters. See also [What is the command line length limit?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=41553). In short, your program is broken in design

Answer (score 1):

The most practical solution is to get your vendor to fix the program.

Failing that, it would be possible (though not easy) to hook the GetCommandLine function so that it returns a string of arbitrary length, although this might just cause the program to crash, depending on how it processes the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Q: "Is there any other way to pass parameters"

A: Yes, pass in a single config file.  Have your program read the config file to get all the parameters.

**For example:**

```
========= Start of "C:\MyConfigFile.txt" =========
    file1
    file2
    ...
    file10000
=================== End of File ==================
```

**Your command:**

```
program.exe "C:\MyConfigFile.txt"
```